# Line graph from date ranges with multiple people

Tags: excel, date, graph

I have a list of tasks in Excel. After each task there is a start date, end date, and # people required to complete the task.

How do I make a line graph that shows how many people we need on any given day, based on the information provided?

(For some reason, this site won't allow me to upload a table or image, but my data is below)

```
Task  /  Start Date / End Date / # People  
A   /   5-11-15 / 5-15-15 / 1  
B  / 5-14-14 / 5-25-15 / 3  
C  / 5-15-15 / 5-20-15 / 2  
D  / 5-18-15 / 5-22-15 / 1  
E / 5-20-15 / 5-27-15 / 2
```

I found a previous post that is similar, but it only uses the COUNTIFS formula - I believe I need to multiply then count. See [Line graph from date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22632324/line-graph-from-date-ranges)

Comment: You will need to use the same type of formula except `SUMIFS` instead of `COUNTIFS`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the screenshot below, the formula in cell G2 (pasted into the entire range G2:K18) is

=SUMIFS($D$2:$D$6,$B$2:$B$6,"<="&$F2,$C$2:$C$6,">="&$F2,$A$2:$A$6,"="&G$1)

L2 is simply =SUM(G2:K2)

I would make a stacked column chart using F1:K18.

[image]